# SL API Account Service createuse method

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to know the title of the matter.

This service has a method createuser(), and it requires templateObject paramter(SoftLayer_User_Customer type). I checked this type and I want to know (1) localeId (2) permissionSystemVersion property details. please give me the meaning of these.

Best Regard.

SoftLayer_Account
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/createUser

SoftLayer_User_Customer
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/softlayer_user_customer

Answer (score 0):

**About localeId property**

This is used to set the user's language information. You can get the locale **id** of language you wish by using the method 
[SoftLayer_Locale::getClosestToLanguageTag](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Locale/getClosestToLanguageTag) as following:

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Locale/getClosestToLanguageTag

Method: POST

{
    "parameters": [
        "it-IT"
    ]
}
```

Below are the language tags you can use when using [SoftLayer_Locale::getClosestToLanguageTag](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Locale/getClosestToLanguageTag)

> - **en-US**   (English)
> - **es-Es**  (Spanish)
> - **fr-FR**  (French)
> - **zh-TW**  (Chinese Traditional)
> - **ko-KR**  (Korean)
> - **ja-JP**  (Japanese)
> - **it-IT**  (Italian)
> - **pt-BR**  (Brazilian Portuguese)
> - **zh-CN**  (Chinese Simplified)
> - **de-DE**  (German)

**About permissionSystemVersion**

This property refers to user's permission system, the system will set it automatically with the default value that currently SL manage, for that reason you don't need to set this value when you create new users.

Comment: Thank you for reply !!

I understood these properties.